# Retrofit 2 calls fail - abstract method "void okhttp3.Callback.onResponse"

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, logan-square

I have imported Retrofit in my project adding following to app.gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
```

Yet now when execute calls the app crashes with following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.my.app, PID: 31176
    java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void okhttp3.Callback.onResponse(okhttp3.Call, okhttp3.Response)"
      at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133)
      at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I need to import specific version of Retrofit (2.0.0-beta3) because of [LoganSquare JSON parser](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare) otherwise I would consider using previous versions of Retrofit. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Retrofit requires certain versions of OkHttp library. And not only that, but if you import logging-interceptor you also need to ensure proper version. So, in my case this helped:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.0-RC1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
```

This is well documented on on [GitHub issue page that's closed](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1475), and thus is not easy to find.

Those who complain about `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void okhttp3.Callback.onFailure(okhttp3.Call, java.io.IOException)"` say that you can remove importing of okhttp3 altogether if you don't use logging-interceptor.

For those who use [LoganSquare](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare), you also need:

```
apt 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare-compiler:1.3.4'
compile 'com.bluelinelabs:logansquare:1.3.4'
compile 'com.github.aurae.retrofit2:converter-logansquare:1.2.
```